# Splitting full date into day/month/quarter/year columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

I have a simple table structure, where my `DATE` column has `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I'd like to split all the dates and `INSERT` them in to my time dimension table, that contains `day`, `month`, `quarter` and `year` columns. I'm not sure how to get going with this (trying with query as insert into).

**EXAMPLE**: `SPLIT 2010-03-01 AND INSERT 2010` into `year` column, `03` into `month` column, `01` into `day` column and `1` into `quarter` column.

Additionally I'd like to assign the names to specific date part (for example `month_name` for `1` is January), is it good practice to store date-name values inside same table?

**Edit**: I've just realized that I probably made big mistake? Is `TIME` dimension in `DATA WAREHOUSE` is supposed to store unique data only (for description purposes?)

Comment: please explain more. do you want select clause to split your date column in day,month , quarter etc?

Comment: I would say leave date as a date field and on select queries, you could filter day, month and year using date functions. Search for sql server date functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically a time dimension implies time (hours, minutes, seconds) or datetime.

It sounds like you just need a date dimension. Most of the work is already done for you here: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

If you are still in the design phase of the fact table, I'd recommend going with date rather than the YYYYMMDD ID format in the tutorial for your PK on the dimension. It's a byte cheaper per row and enables date math. Before SQL 2008, the int dateid format made sense. Now that date is available, it's a more appropriate choice.

As for uniqueness, for hierarchies and associated attribute relationships in ssas I'll typically combine the necessary columns to uniquely identify the period. For example:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) MonthUniqueName
, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4)) + ' Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,GETDATE()) as char(1)) QuarterUniqueName
```

returns

```
MonthUniqueName     QuarterUniqueName
2013 March          2013 Q1
```

Comment: where do you put your column names here?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select Datename(yy,yourDateColumn) as year, Datename(quarter,yourDateColumn), Datename(month, yourDateColumn),Datename(day, yourDatecolumn),CONVERT(varchar(3), yourDateColumn, 100)  from yourTable
```

Assuming you have column type as DateTime

```
Insert into yourTable (yearColumn, quarterColumn, monthColumn, dayColumn) values 
Datename(yy,yourDateColumn) , Datename(quarter,yourDateColumn), Datename(month,  yourDateColumn),Datename(day, yourDatecolumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- First solution: date is stored and day, month, year and quarter are computed
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    Dt DATE NOT NULL,
    DD AS CONVERT(TINYINT, DATEPART(DAY, Dt)) PERSISTED,
    MM AS CONVERT(TINYINT, DATEPART(MONTH, Dt)) PERSISTED,
    YYYY AS CONVERT(SMALLINT, DATEPART(YEAR, Dt)) PERSISTED,
    QQ AS CONVERT(TINYINT, DATEPART(QUARTER, Dt)) PERSISTED
);
INSERT  @Table1
VALUES  (GETDATE());

SELECT * FROM @Table1;

-- Second solution: day, month and year are stored and date and quarter are stored
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
    Dt AS CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, DD-1, DATEADD(MONTH, MM-1, DATEADD(YEAR, YYYY-1, CONVERT(DATE, '00010101',112))))) PERSISTED,
    DD TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(DD BETWEEN 1 AND 31),
    MM TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(MM BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
    YYYY SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK(YYYY BETWEEN 1 AND 9999),
    QQ AS CONVERT(TINYINT, ((MM-1)/3)+1) PERSISTED
);
INSERT  @Table2 (DD, MM, YYYY)
VALUES  (9,3,2013);

SELECT * FROM @Table2;
```

Results:

```
Dt         DD   MM   YYYY   QQ
---------- ---- ---- ------ ----
2013-03-09 9    3    2013   1

Dt         DD   MM   YYYY   QQ
---------- ---- ---- ------ ----
2013-03-09 9    3    2013   1
```